# How to retrieve attachments from Facebook Graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, attachment

I'm struggling to find a method to retrieve attachments from a message via the Graph API.

When I request the message (`m_mid.xxxxxx/attachments`), I get the response:

```
"data": [
  {
    "id": "105446924xxxxxx",
    "mime_type": "application/pdf",
    "name": "some.pdf",
    "size": 89628
  }
]
```

Any way to get the attachment link or the file itself?

Comment: Does it work when requesting the attachment by the ID returned from your API call?

Comment: I haven't tried that, since I'm not able to find how to query an attachment by id via API. The graph explorer only returns the error message `Unsupported get request. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api`

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v5.0/message/attachments) only lists four fields that you can use as query parameters to filter the results, and these are the same as the response to your request.

However, if you remove the `fields` parameter from the request, you'll also get an `image_data` object which includes URLs.

For example:

`https://graph.facebook.com/v5.0/{message_id}/attachments?access_token={page_access_token}`